# It is possible to send a window.print through whatsapp?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to send a window.print via whatsapp://send? to share the current page as pdf document.
Actually the website send only the current url with whatsapp://send?text={url} {text}

```
whatsapp: {
            label: "WhatsApp",
            logo: "fab fa-whatsapp",
            shareUrl: "whatsapp://send?text={url} {text}",
            countUrl: "",
            shareIn: "self"
        },
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is useful, but `print()` creates a PDF version of the current page and allows you to save it in device. Also, there will be options to share them via all the available (possible) apps in your device.

Let me know if this does work or not for your scenario